# How to listen to a TCP port which is already being listened by another app

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, networking, network-programming

I've a plugin which always listening to the port 6002, and i have an ASP.net application which sending messages to the same port and receiving the reply from the plugin on the same port,
Sending is working fine, and the plugin sends a reply on the same port but i don't know how to  catch this reply, when i try to listen to the same port using [Tcplistener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) the start method throws this exception : Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted,

is there any way to catch the received message
Thanks

Comment: From what I can tell it's impossible to open a port once it's being used.

Comment: PLEASE AVOID ALL CAPS WHEN WRITING. It's very rude of you.

Comment: It's being listened by a java plugin, is that means that i can't access it at all ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this problem using this way ,, I know it's old method but it's working !! :

```
'/*Variables Initialization*/
dim objSocket, strServicePort, strIpAddr, strResult, strMsgTo, strMsgResponse   
strServicePort = "6002"
strIpAddr = "127.0.0.1"

'/* Create a TCP/IP socket. */
objSocket = Server.CreateObject("Intrafoundation.TCPClient.3")
objSocket.ClearLog()

'/* Establish socket connection. */
objSocket.Open (strIpAddr,strServicePort)
objSocket.Timeout=60.0 
strMsgTo ="---- Message here ----"

'/* Send request message to plugin  */

objSocket.SendRN(strMsgTo) 

'/* receive XML Request Message from plugin  */
strMsgResponse = objSocket.Recv()
strMsgResponse = Replace(strMsgResponse, vbLf, "")

objSocket.Close()
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are wrongly assuming that the [Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/attbb8f5.aspx) which you get from [TcpListener.AcceptSocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.acceptsocket.aspx) can only be used in one direction.

Sockets can actually be bidirectional. You can use [Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3kd48xs.aspx) to send something, and [Receive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receive.aspx) to <strike>listen for</strike> get the replies. Open one socket, and then use it for both sending and receiving.

Comment: So i can listen !! every body says no and voting down my question !

Comment: no you can't (easily) listen.  "listen" in the TCP sense means listen for new incoming connections.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.

Once a port is opened an exception will be thrown if further attempts are made to utilise that same port from a different source - as you are experiencing right now. There isn't a way to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If you want to inspect traffic you can use winpcap.</strike>

**edit:** I don't think you are asking the right question.  In this case the plugin is the server (listening on port 6002) and your ASP.net app is the client listening on some arbitrary port.  You only need to bind to a different port in your ASP.net app if it also needs to run as a server with the plugin acting s the client.  In this case you should pick a different port even though there are, in fact, ways to make it work when they are both bound to the same port.
In your case though you should just read back responses from the connection you established from the client.